# Flask- HTTP error 500 on local host

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask and I'm trying to learn how to use it. I have a base knowledge of HTML and CSS (enough to make simple pages, not something really fancy).
So, I decided to give Flask a shot, it looks fairly simple to setup at least the basics.

For the moment I'm trying to run a local server (I'm using Windows 7,Python 3.4). Based on some instructions, I set up the project like this:

```
-Flask (main folder)
  routes.py
  /templates
            template.html
            home.html
            welcome.html
  /static
            /css
            /img
            /js
            /font     (for the moment the static folder is empty, except the subfolders)
```

This is the structure of template.html:

```
 <!--DOCTYPE html -->
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            My first Flask App
        </title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

home.html:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h2>Welcome to Flask!</h2>
        <br />
        <p>Click <a href="/welcome">here</a>to go to the welcome page</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And finally, welcome.html:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Sample</h2>
        <p>What a nice page</p>
        <p>Really nice</p>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the code in routes.py:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')      
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/welcome') 
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I try to run the script, the terminal says:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But, when I try to go to localhost:5000 on the browser, I got:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

More specifically, on the terminal says this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2016 14:45:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I know a little about HTTP status code, so I know that code 500 is raised when there is some sort of error. Indeed, when i looked up for information about this problem, every page I found (included here on stackoverflow) suggests that there is some error, either in "routes.py" or in the html pages provided.

Just to be sure, I tried to run this script:

```
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return '''
          <html>
      <head>
        <title>
            My first Flask App
        </title>
      </head>
      <body> 
        <div>
                       hello there!
        </div>
       </body>
           </html>
          '''

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

And this works fine, the server is booted and if I go to localhost:5000 I can see the page correctly. Indeed, on the terminal I see the status code 200, that means "all is ok", if I recall correctly.
I even tried to add more routes, by defining more functions that return the html pages as strings, and all works fine.
I even tried on those pages to use CSS, in the three forms (in line declaration, internal style sheet and external style sheet), it  all works as expected.

So, for the last try, i run the original `routes.py` once again, this time with `app.debug=True`
This is the traceback that i got:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\pyproj\flask\routes.py", line 25, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 777, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.11.3-py3.4.egg\werkzeug\serving.py", line 690, in run_simple
    reloader_type)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.11.3-py3.4.egg\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 252, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
builtins.SystemExit: 0
```

Seriously, there must be something really obvious that I'm missing here: I checked all the codes countless times. To me, all seems fine: all the tags in the HTML documents are properly closed, the {%---%} syntax for the templates seems good written, the code on `routes.py` seems correct also. Furthermore, it generally seems that Flask is working, because if I try to return the html pages as strings written direcly in `routes.py` I can see and interact with the pages. What's going on?

**EDIT**
Based on davidism suggestion, I tried to run the script with `app.run(debug=True,use_reloader=False)`

And this is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "x-wingide-python-shell://70495568/2", line 16, in home

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\templating.py", line 127, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.8-py3.4.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 851, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.8-py3.4.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 812, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.8-py3.4.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 774, in _load_template
    cache_key = self.loader.get_source(self, name)[1]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10.1-py3.4.egg\flask\templating.py", line 64, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
```

I can see the traceback on the browser aswell.

**EDIT 2:**
Thanks to davidism, I tried to run the script from the command line and it works perfectly. Normally I use WingIDE for writing python code, debugging and so on; but in this particular case it seems to conflict with Jinja2. Indeed, I tested several times now, and every time I use WingIDE I get the 500 status code, when I run the script from the command line (even if I simply double-click on the script) it works fine.

Comment: In the last part of the traceback appears raised a `TemplateNotFound(template)` error. Check if you template file is named correctly.

Comment: Thank you miso, we already estabilished what was the problem: it's a conflict between WingIDE and jinja, probably because I messed up something with the installation of Flask